# DevExpress MVC GridView refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I need to refresh DevExpress GridView in the ajax success function after an operation. I am using `gridName.Refresh()` method but javascript is throwing "udefined is not a function" error. But when I write this method to Google Chrome Console window, it is working fine. What is the problem? In Addition my javascript codes are in the different JavaScript file, not among the html codes.

> This is my jquery ajax codes that in the seperated javascript file

```
function sendToMethod(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'html'
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        onCloseClick();
        gv_locations.UnselectRows();//gv_locations is not defined
        gv_locations.Refresh();//there is the same error here too
    })
    .error(function (result) {

    });
}
```

> This is my GridViewPartial.cshtml file

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(g =>
{
    g.Name = "gv_locations";
    g.KeyFieldName = "PublicIP";
    g.SettingsPager.PageSize = 21;
    g.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    g.ClientSideEvents.SelectionChanged = "onGridSelectionChanged";
    g.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.EditFormAndDisplayRow;

    g.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
    g.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = true;
    g.CommandColumn.ShowEditButton = true;
    g.CommandColumn.ShowDeleteButton = true;
    g.CommandColumn.ShowSelectCheckbox = true;
    g.SettingsBehavior.AllowFocusedRow = true;
    g.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Location", Action = "LocationGridViewPartial", id = ViewBag.Type };

    g.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Location", Action = "LocationGridViewInlineUpdate" };
    g.SettingsEditing.DeleteRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Location", Action = "LocationGridViewInlineDelete" };

    g.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Caption = "Client";
        column.FieldName = "ClientID";
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    g.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Caption = "IP";
        column.FieldName = "PublicIP";
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    g.Columns.Add("PublicIPName", "Lokasyon Adı");

    g.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Caption = "Konum Tipi";
        column.FieldName = "SelectedLocationTypeID";
        column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
        var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
        comboBoxProperties.DataSource = AtomicAdminPanel.Models.External.Location.LocationDataProvider.GetLocationTypes();
        comboBoxProperties.TextField = "SelectedLocationTypeName";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "SelectedLocationTypeID";
    });

    g.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Caption = "Oluşturan";
        column.FieldName = "CreatedUser";
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    g.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Caption = "Oluşturma Tarihi";
        column.FieldName = "CreatedDateTime";
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    g.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Caption = "Değiştiren";
        column.FieldName = "ChangedUser";
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    g.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Caption = "Değiştime Tarihi";
        column.FieldName = "ChangedDateTime";
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    g.Columns.Add("IsActive", "Aktif", MVCxGridViewColumnType.CheckBox);

    MVCxGridViewColumn col_listType = new MVCxGridViewColumn("LocationListType");
    col_listType.Visible = false;

    if (ViewBag.Id == "Online")
    {
        MVCxGridViewColumn col_online = new MVCxGridViewColumn("IsOnline", "Çevrimiçi", MVCxGridViewColumnType.Image);
        col_online.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("<img src='../../Content/Image/statusOnline.png'/>");
        });
        g.Columns.Add(col_online);
    }
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Comment: I think you should show some code.

Comment: I wrote my codes as an answer. Because my codes are too long as don't fit here :)

Comment: The error says that `gv_locations` is not defined. Is the javascript file on the same page as the GridView?

Comment: Not design time. Because Devexpress says "The page that includes the gridview doesn't include another html or javascript codes. You must seperate the page that includes GridView." Other functions in the same javascript file are working fine for the GridView.

Comment: I mean on the browser's page, not partial view where the grid is located. Do you mean that the functions are working fine for the same `gv_locations` GridView?

Comment: Yes. But there is a weird. When I write the gv_locations.Refresh(); method to Google chrome console window, it is working.

Comment: no answer? Please help me

Comment: Anybody have an idea about this problem?

Comment: Are you using this ajax method to render the grid ?
or you just refresh the already rendered grid in success of the ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should write `window.gv_locations` and next make sure a view that contains the js script see this grid (view should contains grid and script). Give me response if it works.

Comment: If `gv_locations` is undefined, it will still be undefined when accessed as `window.gv_locations`.